# First EJB - NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, ejb-3.1

I would like to learn how to work with EJBs so I started to read "Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1 6th edition". After creating first example (FirstEJB Example chapter) I've got problem with `NameNotFoundException`. As far as I know it means that EJB is not visible / doesn't exist on container. The project seems to be very simple but I don't know how to solve the problem. Any help? Project can be found here https://github.com/pepuch/EJB-ch04-firstejb. This is how I worked with this project.

1. I've built `ejb` project using `gradle clean build` command and deployed created `ejb-1.0.jar` to server using glassfish admin site.
2. I've started client unit test using `gradle clean test`. This test shows `NameNotFoundException` exception.

In few words project contains two subprojects:

1. ejb - project creates EJB jar
2. client - project contains only one unit test which try to create and use EJB

**[UPDATE]**

I started application on jboss server and it works. This is how code looks like for jboss:

// class which uses EJB

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
context = new InitialContext();
final String JNDI_NAME_CALC = "SimpleCalculatorBean/remote";
CalculatorCommonBusiness calc = (CalculatorCommonBusiness)context.lookup(JNDI_NAME_CALC);
calc.add(2,3,4,5);
```

// jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099
```

I still can't start app on glassfish server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if the EJB is created. In order to do this, check your application server log. It should write doen the name of your EJB being published. Created? Check the name.

Step 2:
Check that the package of your interface-stub is the same as published EJB`s remote/local interface. It might be the reason.

UPDATE:

```
calc = (SimpleCalculatorBean) namingContext.lookup(JNDI_NAME_CALC);
```

You should get the interface of EJB, not the bean directly.
Moreover, @Local interface on EJB might not work - probably you need to make it @Remote.

Comment: 1. I've checked log and I found `Portable JNDI names for EJB SimpleCalculatorBean: [java:global/ejb-1.0/SimpleCalculatorBean, ...]` so this is correct. If you can, please check source code on github.

2. As far as I understand you - bean class implements interface so it must be correct. Can you wrote what do you mean?

Comment: Still without success on glassfish server. I tested app on jboss server and it works on it.

Comment: Did you change the interface to Remote?

Comment: By the way, you should also use the global JNDI name with Glassfish which is: java:global:/[EJBJarName]/[YourBeanName]![YourRemoteInterfaceName] + Glassfish does not require any JNDI properties file.

Comment: Yes, I've changed interface to `@Remote` and it works fine on jboss. I've also tried to use global JNDI name with glassfish but without success. You wrote that Glassfish doesn't require jndi.properties but if will not pass this file to classpath application returns exception that I need to pass properties to create context.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like ive had the same problem once. You should add all jars in the /lib folder of your Glassfish server into the classpath when starting the client application. Your problem happens because it cannot find the JNDI properties file which is located by default in the glassfish /lib folder.

Comment: glassfish doesn't handle ejb @remote interfaces correctly?  use wildfly?